# How do Facebook mobile apps sign API calls to Facebook servers for authentication?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I was monitoring the traffic of Facebook Android app and saw that the API call that handles the User log in has a parameter called "sig". I read about it and found that this parameter is added to sign the API call so that Facebook servers can differentiate between a legal API call and malicious calls.

How does the Facebook Android App/SDK generate this "sig" parameter and how do the Facebook servers verify the authenticity of the caller?